# IntelliJ IDEA Gradle error: Failed to notify build listener

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I use Gradle 7.0 with Kotlin DSL and IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) and openjdk15 on Linux.

When I want to import my Gradle project I get the following error message:

```sh
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify build listener.
> 'java.lang.String org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

When I run the same thing from a terminal without IDEA, it works just fine. When I change the version to 6.8.1 it also works just fine.

How do you fix this error or is this a known problem and I have to wait for another release of either tool?

Comment: Is it possible to check the issue with the latest IDE version?

Comment: I already did install all automatic updates. Can you get more recent updates by manual install? Note that I am on Linux.

Comment: What version is mentioned in "Help | About" dialog? Did you check for updates from IDE ("Help | Check for updates")?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) - and yes I did check for updates from the IDE. Nothing new available there E: checking from updates multiple times returns different updates.

Comment: Please try to download 2021.1 version from official site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the Intellij-IDEA 2017.3 on my Mac. This was resolved when I try IntelliJ-IDEA 2021.2(Community Edition).